# Dynamically created button with click and AsyncPostBackTrigger

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating buttons programmatically at page load in my asp.net page and attempting to wire up their clicks and not having any luck. What I need is for the buttons to be generated, and then have their clicks addressed to a sub (previously the sub was pre-handled by non generated buttons) and have their AsyncPostBackTrigger wired up. This all worked before I started to try to generate the buttons on load.

```
Dim supplierButton As Button
selectButtonsPanel.Controls.Clear()
For Each row As DataRow In supplierDataTable.Rows
    If bizClass.dbCStr(row.Item(0)) <> "Stock" Then
        supplierButton = New Button
        supplierButton.Text = "Select " & row.Item(0).ToString
        supplierButton.ID = "select" & row.Item(0).ToString & "Button"
        AddHandler supplierButton.Click, AddressOf selectButton_Click

        Dim trig As New AsyncPostBackTrigger
        trig.ControlID = supplierButton.UniqueID
        trig.EventName = "Click"
        UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trig)

        selectButtonsPanel.Controls.Add(supplierButton)
    End If
Next row
```

Comment: You're running into issues with the Page Lifecycle model when you do this. Your problem is that when .NET needs to attach the events on postback, the controls aren't there yet, so you've likely added them too late in the life cycle (you should likely use the init events for creation). Dynamic controls are nasty and often can be solved in other ways - but if you're up for it - I'd start here to understand what goes on behind the scene: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: You convinced me to just use a repeater. It is the better way anyhow I believe.